# Magento 2 :Uber Theme Data Migration Tool Error

Tags: magento2.2

I want to migrate magento 1.9.2.2 data like customer,order,product,categories,attribute etc in **Magento 2.2.2** And
for I have use https://github.com/ubertheme/module-ubdatamigration(data migration tool)

but its showing error after installing.

I have attached screen shot also.
please help for this error[image]

[image]

Comment: Contact Uber Theme support, I used it a while ago, It was working for me fine.

Comment: thanks, it working for me also...
but i have one query is any free data-migration-tool git available that migrate hole data menace Order ,sales data etc...

Comment: Yes, You can use this, https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool